# How to throw custom exception when using Spring webclient exchange method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I have created a reusable method that returns the headers, status, and body of an HTTP call using the Spring webclient's `exchange` method. I want to capture the 4xx and 5xx errors in the method itself and log the response body. However, i am not able to return/throw custom exception when 4xx or 5xx error occurs.

Here is the reusable method -

```
    private Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<String>>> exchangeGet(AutomationHttpRequest request) throws AutomationException {
        oLogger.debug("Invoking Exchange request for - {}", request.getName());
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(request.getUri())
                .headers(request.getHeaderList())
                .exchangeToMono(Mono::just)
                .map( response -> {

//                    Approach 1
//                    if(response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()){
//                        oLogger.error("Client side error for request {}, status {}", request.getName(), response.statusCode());
//                        oLogger.error("response body - ");
//                        response.toEntity(String.class).subscribe(error -> oLogger.error(String.valueOf(error.getBody())));
//                        throw new AutomationException("");
//                    }
//
//                    Approach 2
//                    if(response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()){
//                        oLogger.error("Client side error for request {}, status {}", request.getName(), response.statusCode());
//                        oLogger.error("response body - ");
//                        response.toEntity(String.class).subscribe(error -> oLogger.error(String.valueOf(error.getBody())));
//                        return Mono.error(new AutomationException(""));
//                    }

                    HttpHeaders headers = response.headers().asHttpHeaders().entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(entry -> !entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Transfer-Encoding"))
                            .collect(HttpHeaders::new,
                                    (httpHeaders, entry) -> httpHeaders.addAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()), HttpHeaders::putAll);
                    return ResponseEntity.status(response.statusCode())
                            .headers(headers).body(response.bodyToMono(String.class));
                });
    }
```

Note - `AutomationException` is a custom exception class.

If you observe the commented out code, you will notice that in Approach 1, i tried throwing an exception, but it complains that the error is not handled, which means the function (map) is expected to handle it and not throw it from the reusable `exchangeGet` method. Approach 2, does not work as the return parameterized Mono object's type does not match the method return type. I cannot use generics as there would be issues with Sonar lint.

Basically, the effect that I am trying to obtain is as follows -

```
    private Mono<String> get(AutomationHttpRequest request) throws AutomationException {
        oLogger.debug("Invoking GET request for - {}", request.getName());
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(request.getUri())
                .headers(request.getHeaderList())
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                    oLogger.error(LOG_CLIENT_ERROR, request.getName(), response.statusCode());
                    response.toEntity(String.class).subscribe(error -> oLogger.error(String.valueOf(error.getBody())));
                    return Mono.error(new AutomationException(CLIENT_EXCEPTION));
                }).onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
                    oLogger.error(LOG_SERVER_ERROR, request.getName(), response.statusCode());
                    response.toEntity(String.class).subscribe(error -> oLogger.error(String.valueOf(error.getBody())));
                    return Mono.error(new AutomationException(SERVER_EXCEPTION));
                })
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

In the above, `retrieve` is used instead of `exchange` and therefore I can handle the 4xx and 5xx errors individually. I am also able to log the status, and body in case of error sceanrios.

How do I achieve the same with `exchange` method. I do not want to log the exception on the consumer class. Besides logging, i want to standardize the exception thrown in error scenarios such as the `retrive` method.

Note - I need to use `exchange` in order to access the response headers and body. If there is a better way to achieve the same, kindly advice.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is `.exchangeToMono(Mono::just)`

why you decided to just ignore this operator and then do all your logic in `map` i just strange.

`Map` is used to map one type to a another synchronously. Which means that you map it from type `T` to type `U`.

Why it doesn't work is because you are trying to map it from type `T` to type `U` and `Mono<V>` in the same function. So what does this mean?

in your map function you are returning the type `ResponseEntity`. But you also want to return a `Mono.error` a couple of rows before. These are two different types and you can't return 2 different types from a function. Thats not how the type system works.

What you need to do is to return `Mono`.

So remove the `map` function and move your logic to the `exchangeToMono` its litteraly the name of the function, here you turn your exchange into a Mono or a Mono.error.

Also use `ServerResponse#build` instead of `ResponseEntity`

And all of this is documented in the docs for WebClient so please read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange